# maroun85 - react-native-background-geolocation - How to determine accuracy of location fetching?

Tags: react-native, geolocation

First of all i would like to say [react-native-background-geolocation](https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation) is an awesome plugin to background location tracking in react-native.:) In my application i need to determine accuracy of each location point fetch by the plugin. There is a parameter called "accuracy"
in the location response object. But i cannot understand the values it holds. Can anyone explain about that accuracy parameter works or show me a different way to determine accuracy of each location point.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accuracy is in meters and can be thought of as the radius of a circle whose center is at the Lat/Lng coordinates you received. Your actual location is "guaranteed" to be at some point in that circle. IOW if you use google maps api to draw a circle on the map with a center at the Lat/Lng and with a diameter of twice the value returned then you can say you are "somewhere" in that circle.

The smaller the returned value the more accurate. Make sense?

It's just a shame Chrome and Webkit don't implement this [native](https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen) Background Geolocation :-( Then we'd have no need for dodgy plugins.